# I hava a value and I want to get its key in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Sample structure of mongo record:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("562cc10f21af784f532de231"),
   "name" : "Roger Federer",
   "Mirka Federer" : [ 
       "wife", 
       "married", 
       "best friend"
   ],
   "34" : [ 
       "age", 
       "years old"
   ]
}
```

Mirka Federer is a field. The correspoding items are its values

Its like Field: Value

We want to find the field given a value

Comment: Could you please try to reformulate your question? It is totally unclear what you mean under key/value here at all as mongo does not store key/value pairs. It stores documents and you could surely name their `_id` as key, but this does not look like you want the `_id`. But even then, what is the value?

Comment: Sorry I am pretty new to MongoDB.

Comment: But what is the question? Please try to formulate it again from scratch as I really do not understand what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: For example: Mirka Federer is a Field and the corresponding items are value. Field: Value and we want find a field given a value

Comment: You have a very poor data structure to accomplish this: your "values" are lists. In this situation your best bet is to programmatically iterate though your key/list pairs and compare the list content to your search condition breaking out when it matches. Totally inefficient and would be done outside of the DB.